# ¿Por que al seleccionar un elemento por clase no funciona mi evento y por id si funciona?

Tags: javascript, html

El problema que tengo es que al momento de seleccionar  por:

```
const numero_12 = document.getElementsByClassName("numero1");
```

la funcion que debe imprimir el numero por consola no funciona, en cambio...
al seleccionar por:

```
const numero_12 = document.getElementByID("numer");
```

Si funciona

Mi HTLM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!--Import fonts-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--Import css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Calc</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="display">
          <div class="input">0</div>
        </div>
        <button class="number numero1" id="numer">1</button>
        <button class="number">2</button>
        <button class="number">3</button>
        <button class="operator">+</button>
        <button class="number">4</button>
        <button class="number">5</button>
        <button class="number">6</button>
        <button class="operator">-</button>
        <button class="number">7</button>
        <button class="number">8</button>
        <button class="number">9</button>
        <button class="operator">*</button>
        <button class="number">0</button>
        <button class="operator">.</button>
        <button class="operator">c</button>
        <button class="operator">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

MI JS

```
const btn_number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
const numero_12 = document.getElementsByClassName("numero1");

numero_12.onclick = function () {
  console.log("Soy Numero");
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo leer la documentación de la función [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). ¿Que es lo que devuelve?

Comment: @Marcos Disuclpa, habia puesto mal aqui pero en codigo si lo tengo correctamente escrito. Entonces `document.getElementById` retorna algo distinto a `document.getElementsByClassName()` ???

Comment: @Marcos gracias por el regaño bro, si debería enseñarme a hacer eso :(

Comment: Mi intención no era regañar a nadie (_disculpa si sono así_). Solo quería ayudarte a que vos puedas descubrir el error. **PD:** Si ya encontraste la solución, recordá que podes responder a tu propia pregunta. Dentro de un par de días vas a poder marcarla con acertada.